# Data warehouse design: how to design fact and dimension table with changed delivery date

Tags: database, relational-database, data-warehouse

I am trying to create a PO info data warehouse but i am facing problems with the vendors delayed deliveries. I would like to track the changes when the vendor late on delivery and change the delivery date. How should i organize the table to track the changes, should i put the delivery date in a dimension table or fact table? any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just put everything in a single Purchase Order table.

```
Purchase Order
-------------_
Expected Delivery Timestamp
Actual Delivery Timestamp
Purchase Order ID
Purchase Order Creation Timestamp
...
```

The primary key would be (Expected Delivery Timestamp descending, Purchase Order ID).

You would create another unique index on (Actual Delivery Timestamp descending, Purchase Order ID, Expected Delivery Timestamp).

This single table would allow you to write queries like, "How many deliveries were more than a week late in the 2nd quarter of 2016?"